# Eclipse GUI Errors on Java windows

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Hello I was wondering if you know why my Eclipse is giving these GUI errors (as seen below the text box is patchy) I have just updated Java and it did not seem to help.

Thank you

[image: A example of the GUI Error]

Comment: This is most likely not an eclipse fault, but OS/Java. Tried running it through the compiled .jar?

Comment: What is the code under the dialog? This isn't an eclipse dialog, eclipse uses SWT and this is a Swing dialog.

Comment: I did try though a complied.jar but it does not seem to open. Unsure as to what is wrong I am going to try on my work computer and not the laptop later on today hopefully it works there